# C++ already defined in Main.obj

Tags: c++, c++11, header, lnk2005

I added a header with some funtions. But im having LNK2005 errors saying the variables declared in main.h are already defined in main.obj.
How could i fix this?

*My main.cpp*

```
#include "Main.h"
//#include "Service.h"


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
...
```

My Main.h

```
#include ...
...
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
using std::filesystem::current_path;
using namespace std;
int is_receiving = 0;
bool sqlserver = false;
std::string opt_host_name1; /* HOST */
std::string opt_user_name1; /* USERNAME */
std::string opt_password1; /* PASSWORD */
const unsigned int opt_port_num = 3306; /* PORT */
const char* opt_socket_name = NULL; /* SOCKET NAME, DO NOT CHANGE */
std::string opt_db_name1; /* DATABASE NAME */
unsigned int opt_flags = 0; /* CONNECTION FLAGS, DO NOT CHANGE */
#define BUFSIZE 512

string aetitle(string called, string calling);
bool is_older_than(const fs::path& path, int hrs);
```

My Service.cpp

```
#include "Main.h"

string aetitle(string called, string calling)
{
...
}
bool is_older_than(const fs::path& path, int hrs)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Don't define variables in headers.

Comment: Seems like a missing header guard. Can you add ```#pragma once``` at the beginning of your main.h and try again?

Comment: @Zacki forgot to put here but already had #pragma once